# How to set focus to particular row in Xceed Grid for .NET

Tags: .net, xceed-datagrid

I am new to using Xceed Grid for .NET. There is set focus in .NET but not on Xceed. Can you please help me how to get the same ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
this.gridControl1.CurrentRow = this.gridControl1.DataRows[100];
this.gridControl1.CurrentRow.BringIntoView();
this.gridControl1.FirstVisibleRow = this.gridControl1.CurrentRow;
this.gridControl1.SelectedRows.Add(this.gridControl1.CurrentRow);
```

Calling the BringIntoView on the DataRow will let the GridControl scroll all the way to where the DataRow is located. Setting the FirstVisibleRow on the GridControl to your CurrentRow will have the DataRow at the top of the GridControl's view.